# Upgrade Magento 2.4.1 to 2.4.2

Tags: magento2.4.2

I am trying to upgrade Magento Version 2.4.1 to 2.4.2 and getting an errors

```
Magento Open Source 2.4.2 is trying to change the existing order of the require section.
Local order:
   [
      magento/composer-root-update-plugin,
      magento/product-community-edition
   ]
Magento Open Source 2.4.2 order:
   [
      magento/product-community-edition,
      magento/composer-root-update-plugin
   ] but it will not be changed. Re-run using --use-default-magento-values or --interactive-magento-conflicts to override with the Magento order.
Updating composer.json for Magento Open Source 2.4.2 ...
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information                                                                   Updating dependencies (including require-dev)         
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - The requested package dealerdirect/phpcodesniffer-composer-installer (locked at v0.5.0, required as ^0.7.0) is satisfiable by dealerdirect/phpcodesniffer-composer-installer[v0.5.0] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
  Problem 2
    - Conclusion: don't install magento/product-community-edition 2.4.2
    - Conclusion: remove amzn/amazon-pay-and-login-magento-2-module 4.0.4
    - Conclusion: don't install amzn/amazon-pay-and-login-magento-2-module 4.0.4
    - Installation request for magento/product-community-edition 2.4.2 -> satisfiable by magento/product-community-edition[2.4.2].
    - Conclusion: don't install amzn/amazon-pay-and-login-magento-2-module 4.0.4
    - magento/product-community-edition 2.4.2 requires amzn/amazon-pay-and-login-magento-2-module 4.2.0 -> satisfiable by amzn/amazon-pay-and-login-magento-2-module[4.2.0].
    - Can only install one of: amzn/amazon-pay-and-login-magento-2-module[4.2.0, 4.0.4].
    - Can only install one of: amzn/amazon-pay-and-login-magento-2-module[4.2.0, 4.0.4].
    - Installation request for amzn/amazon-pay-and-login-magento-2-module (locked at 4.0.4) -> satisfiable by amzn/amazon-pay-and-login-magento-2-module[4.0.4].


Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.

The native 'composer require' command failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content from before the Magento root update.
```

Comment: run composer update with the --use-default-magento-values flag.

Comment: @paj, is this the right command to run `composer update --use-default-magento-values`

Comment: yes, if you are using the composer update root plugin https://github.com/magento/composer-root-update-plugin/

Answer (score 3):

For fixed the issue in your **composer.json**

**Change order**

magento/composer-root-update-plugin,
magento/product-community-edition

**TO**

magento/product-community-edition,
magento/composer-root-update-plugin

**Update Version**

"dealerdirect/phpcodesniffer-composer-installer": "^0.5.0"

**To**

"dealerdirect/phpcodesniffer-composer-installer": "^0.7.0",

Comment: Is there another fix for this?

Comment: i used as per answer it was worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Change the require order in composer.json file in your root directory.

[image]

Now run the upgrade command "composer require magento/product-community-edition=2.4.2 --no-update"